# Google GSON: Deserialize JSON data to Java

Tags: java, json, gson

We are using Google GSON for deserializing JSON data to Java object. See below sample JSON data and corresponding POJO class. I am able to deserialize "name" and "phoneNumber" fields. But for **"deparments"** field, I see Null. Can you please help me how can I deserialize **"deparments"** field?

My JSON:

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "phoneNumber": "000000000",
  "deparments": "xyz,abc,wyz,djkf, iii"
}
```

The class:

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String deparments;

    // getters and setters
}
```

CustomerDeserializer.java:

```
...
Gson gson = new Gson();
CustomerInfo customerInfo = gson.fromJson(reader, CustomerInfo.class);
```

Comment: perhaps the Gson spellchecker dropped the property

Comment: Can you paste in the actual code?  This clearly isn't it as there are spelling mistakes (e.g. "Privaet") and case inconsistencies, making it impossible to diagnose the actual problem.

Comment: Your code works for me, for GSON: 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Recheck your JSON source. I think you just have some objects with key: depar**t**ments, instead of *deparments*.

Anyway next code works for me:

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String deparments;

    // getters and setters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getDeparments() {
        return deparments;
    }
    public void setDeparments(String deparments) {
        this.deparments = deparments;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerInfo{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", deparments='" + deparments + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

@Test
public void desJson(){
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"customer\",\n" +
            "  \"phoneNumber\": \"000000000\",\n" +
            "  \"deparments\": \"xyz,abc,wyz,djkf, iii\"\n" +
            "}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    CustomerInfo customerInfo = gson.fromJson(json, CustomerInfo.class);
    System.out.println(customerInfo);
}
```

the output is:

> CustomerInfo{name='customer', phoneNumber='000000000',
>   deparments='xyz,abc,wyz,djkf, iii'}

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste this code below

```
public class CustomerInfo {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @SerializedName("deparments")
    private String deparments;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this, CustomerInfo.class);
    }
}
```

and Deserialize it like the code below

```
CustomerInfo customerInfo = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, CustomerInfo.class);
```

Hope this helps you.